# instanceof in SpEL

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

i have a class with the method:
Code:

```
List<Entity> getData() {...}
```

and some classes which extends Entity: Project, Phase, Invoice, Payment.

and i would like to do something like this:

```
@PostFilter("filterObject instanseof Project ? filterObject.manager == principal : filterObject instanceof Phase ? filterObject.project.manager == principal : 
filterObject instanceof Invoice ? filterObject.phase.project == principal : filterObject instanceof Payment ? filterObject.invoice.phase.project.manager == principal : true")
```

is it a legal? or how to use "instanceof" correctly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The correct syntax for SpEL would be like `filterObject instanceof T(Project)`. (Please see [SpEL section 6.5.6.1 - Relational operators](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/expressions.html))