# Use 'instanceof' with @EventListener condition Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-el

Is there any way to check the type of source in `@EventListener` **condition** ?

Example:-
Assume that i have a generic class as shown below:-

```java
public class EntityObjectEvent<T> extends ApplicationEvent {

    private EventType type;

    public EntityObjectEvent(T source, EventType type) {
        super(source);
        this.type = type;
    }

    public EventType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T getSource() {
        return (T) super.getSource();
    }
}
```

And i have 3 `@EventListener` methods, each one must activated on a specific entity as shown below:-

```java
@Service
public class EntityObjectEventListener {

    @Async
    @EventListener(condition = "#event.source instanceof Entity1")
    public void entity1EventListener(EntityObjectEvent<Entity1> event) {
        System.err.println("entity-1 event received => " + event.getClass());
    }

    @Async
    @EventListener(condition = "#event.source instanceof Entity2")
    public void entity2EventListener(EntityObjectEvent<Entity2> event) {
        System.err.println("entity-2 event received => " + event.getClass());
    }

    @Async
    @EventListener(condition = "#event.source instanceof Entity3")
    public void entity3EventListener(EntityObjectEvent<Entity3> event) {
        System.err.println("entity-3 event received => " + event.getClass());
    }
}
```

The problem is `@EventListener` doesn't check the type of source, it just throws an exception as shown below:-

```java
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'Entity1' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.context.event.EventExpressionRootObject' - maybe not public or not valid?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:217)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:91)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OperatorInstanceof.getValueInternal(OperatorInstanceof.java:61)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OperatorInstanceof.getValueInternal(OperatorInstanceof.java:38)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:117)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:308)
    at org.springframework.context.event.EventExpressionEvaluator.condition(EventExpressionEvaluator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.shouldHandle(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:325)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:166)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:162)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.lambda$multicastEvent$0(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:140)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

How can i do it in the right way using **SpEL** ?

Comment: I use spring boot verion 2.4.5

Comment: Well by not using spel? Just write a method that dispatches to the correct one. Also `Entity3` doesn't look like the correct class, you would need th FQCN of the class and not the simple name. You mention an error, but you don't include the error (**full stacktrace please**) in your question.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for your reply. I have tried to put the FQCN of the class before posting the problem and it didn't work. Also, i've implemented one listener that can handle all entities events and check the object type by (if else) but that makes the code more complex and hard to read.

Comment: I would argue against that it is more complex. The SpEL is more complex as it is more magic and you can have scattered around functionality, now you have everything in 1 method. But that is IMHO. Please provide the exception you get, currently there is too little information (as it is also a dumbed down version of what you actually have instead of actual code).

Comment: @M.Deinum i have added the exception

Comment: Your SpEL expression is wrong, the class needs to be inside `T()` so the expression should read `#event.source instanceof T(your.full.class.name.here)`. Else it will be parsed as an expression. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628437/instanceof-in-spel (marking this as a duplicate).